# How to move the field note at the end of the reference

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

I am using the `note`field to add the original publication date and I would like to print it at the end of the reference instead of before the publisher information.

I had a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) and tried to come out with a similar solution. Still my macro doesn't work: the `note`field doesn't change position.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@book{habermas_structural_1989,
    address = {Cambridge, {MA}},
    title = {The structural transformation of the public sphere: {An} inquiry into a category of bourgeois society},
    publisher = {MIT {Press}},
    author = {Habermas, Jürgen},
    translator = {Burger, Thomas and Lawrence, Frederick},
    year = {1989},
    note = {({Original} work published 1962)}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}


% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    hyperref=true,
    backref=false,
    firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+note}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\space}%
  \usebibmacro{note}%
  \newunit}

% Recommended by biblatex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Set language
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{habermas_structural_1989}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you be OK with using `addendum` instead of `note` (see [p. 14 of the `biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf): "This [the `addendum` field] is similar to the `note` field except that it is printed at the end of the bibliography entry.")? If you are interested, there are solutions of automatically mapping `note` to `addendum` via Biber.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) states on page 14: "This [the `addendum` field] is similar to the `note` field except that it is printed at the end of the bibliography entry."

So instead of `note` it is better to use `addendum`.
`biblatex-apa` automatically wraps `addendum` into parentheses, so there is no need to do that manually.

NB: It is always better to let `biblatex` handle such cases: It is quite tiresome to always remember to put the parentheses around the words, and what if you want to get rid of them?

So the entry in the `.bib` file should look like this.

```
@book{habermas_structural_1989_addendum,
    address = {Cambridge, {MA}},
    title = {The structural transformation of the public sphere: {An} inquiry into a category of bourgeois society},
    publisher = {MIT {Press}},
    author = {Habermas, Jürgen},
    translator = {Burger, Thomas and Lawrence, Frederick},
    year = {1989},
    addendum = {{Original} work published 1962}
}
```

---

If you can not be bothered to use `addendum` manually, you can make `biblatex`/`biber` do the mapping for you.

Just add this to the preamble.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=note, final]
      \step[fieldset=addendum, origfieldval, final]
      \step[fieldset=note, null]
    }
  }
}
```

It will copy the `note` field into the `addendum` field (only if the latter one is empty), the `note` field will be removed afterwards.

You can then use `note` as usual.

---

The least convenient way is to modify all the drivers defined in `apa.bbx`. Unfortunately `apa.bbx` does not use any macros to print `note` and `addendum`, but the bare `\printfield{note}` and `\printfield{addendum}`.

In `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}` we find:

```
...
\printfield{series}%
\newunit\newblock
\printfield{note}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{location+publisher}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
\setunit*{\addspace}\newblock
\usebibmacro{origyear}%
\newunit\newblock
\printfield{addendum}%
\newunit\newblock
...
```

You could manually move all the `\printfield{note}` near `\printfield{addendum}` like so

```
...
\printfield{series}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{location+publisher}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
\setunit*{\addspace}\newblock
\usebibmacro{origyear}%
\newunit\newblock
\printfield{addendum}%
\newunit\newblock
\printfield{note}%
\newunit\newblock
...
```

or you could `xpatch` all the drivers via

```
\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\newunit\newblock
   \printfield{note}%
  }
  {}%
  {\typeout{successfully temporarily removed note}}
  {\typeout{failed to temporarily remove note}}

\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\printfield{addendum}%
  }
  {\printfield{addendum}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \printfield{note}}%
  {\typeout{successfully re-added note after addendum}}
  {\typeout{failed re-add note after addendum}}
```

You will have to do this for all drivers though.
So you might want to wrap this into a command

```
\newcommand{\movenote}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\newunit\newblock
     \printfield{note}}
    {}%
    {\typeout{successfully temporarily removed note (in driver #1)}}
    {\typeout{failed to temporarily remove note  (in driver #1)}}%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\printfield{addendum}}
    {\printfield{addendum}%
     \newunit\newblock
     \printfield{note}}%
    {\typeout{successfully re-added note after addendum  (in driver #1)}}
    {\typeout{failed re-add note after addendum  (in driver #1)}}%
}
```

To patch a driver, use `\movenote{article}`, you can call this command for all drivers like this:

```
\makeatletter
\forlistloop{\movenote}{\blx@datamodel@entrytypes}
\makeatother
```

or

```
\makeatletter
\def\do#1{\movenote{#1}}
\abx@doentrytypes
\makeatother
```

Comment: I implemented the first suggestion. I recoded my Zotero BibTex.js translator to write the `extra` field as `addendum` instead of `note`. It was actually quite straightforward: `writeField("note", item.extra);` was replaced with `writeField("addendum", item.extra);`

Comment: The added loop along all entrytypes is especially interesting!