# Changing order of information each reference in bibtex and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographystyle

I am using the following command to display my bibliography:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
style=numeric,
maxbibnames=50,
url=false,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
```

My bibliography entries look like:

```
@article{ ref1,
    author = {Last1, F. and Last2, F. and Last3, F.},
    title = {Some title},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = 2019,
    volume = 300,
    pages = "2",
    month = "",
    note={Want to insert a note at the end of each entry}
}
```

It puts the note text before the page number, like this:

> F. Last1, F. Last2, and F. Last3. "Some title". Journal 300 (2019). Want to insert a note at the end of each entry, p. 2.

but I want the note after the page number instead, like this:

> F. Last1, F. Last2, and F. Last3. "Some title". Journal 300 (2019), p. 2. Want to insert a note at the end of each entry.

How can I do that?

Please assume I know nothing about editing style files and such, because I have looked at them and they make no sense to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: If you want to add something to the end of an entry, use `addendum` instead of `note`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138913/35864.