# Citation customisation

Tags: biblatex, citing

Greeting to everyone !

I am helping a friend to write a law-oriented thesis and I am struggling to set in the correct way the citation. In these types of thesis we usually have 2 different types of citations:

- **THE FOOT NOTE CITATION**: in which we found "Author + title + publisher + year + ... + **comment of the writer**";
- **THE END THESIS BIBLIOGRAPHY**: in which we found the standard bibliography
  WITHOUT the **comment of the writer**.

The problem is the following:

THIS IS MY MAIN:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Dimensione dell'area di scrittura -> tra parentesi
% (larghezza, altezza)
\usepackage[a4paper, total={15cm, 20.8cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-ibid, labeldateparts]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}



\title{FORMALISING ALGORITHMIC FAIRNESS AND UNFAIRNESS IN LEGAL EXPERIENCE}
\author{Veronica Paternolli}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

[...]


\clearpage
\tableofcontents 

\clearpage
\input{sections/introduction}
[...]
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And this is how it look like now:
[image]

The question is the following:

We would like to have while using `\footcite{ }`:

- In the footer [in this order] just "author", "title", "publisher, "date", and, if present, "note".
- In the end bibliography everything else.

Comment: In the footnote part i do not want any other information, no doi, no url, and so on.

Anyway, thank you soo much for your time! We really appreciate that!

Comment: Could you add an example of the .bib file?

Answer (score 1):

To put the note at the end, use `addendum` instead of `note` in the bibitems, see [this answer by moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139010/101651).

To remove it from the Bibliography, use:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{addendum}%
}
```

Here is a complete MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{biblio.bib}
@book{wolfgang2017introduction,
  title={Introduction to artificial intelligence},
  author={Wolfgang, Ertel},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Springer},
  addendum = {{This} is a note about this book.}
}
@inproceedings{dymitruk2021borderlands,
  title={Borderlands of the Law and Technology: from Digital Machines to LegalTech},
  author={Dymitruk, Maria},
  booktitle={Legal Tech},
  pages={67--80},
  year={2021},
  organization={Nomos Verlagsgesellschaft mbH \& Co. KG},
  addendum = {{This} is a note about this conference proceedings.}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={15cm, 20.8cm}]{geometry}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} no more needed
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-ibid, labeldateparts]{biblatex}

% no note in Bibliography
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{addendum}%
}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}% better loaded at last

\title{FORMALISING ALGORITHMIC FAIRNESS AND UNFAIRNESS IN LEGAL EXPERIENCE}
\author{Pippo Pluto}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\tableofcontents 

\clearpage
\section{Introduction}

Something with a footnote citation.\footcite{wolfgang2017introduction}

Something with another footnote citation.\footcite{dymitruk2021borderlands}

\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Footnote citations:

[image]

Bibliography:

[image]